# Regex to Grab City, State, Zip

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to make a regex that can handle input like either:

1. Beverly Hills, CA
2. Beverly Hills, CA 90210

I have this:

```
^(.+)[,\\s]+(.+)\s+(\d{5})?$
```

It works for the #2 case, but not #1. If I change the `\s+` to `\s*` then it works for #1 but not #2.

You can play around with it here: http://rubular.com/r/oqKBJ4r8cq

Comment: Usual disclaimer applies: regexen are brittle and will break in interesting ways on malformed data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(.+)[,\\s]+(.+?)\s*(\d{5})?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/qS0e5vAQnT

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

`^([^,]+),\s([A-Z]{2})(?:\s(\d{5}))?$`

This expression works on both examples, captures each piece of the address in separate groups, and properly handles whitespace.

Here is how it breaks down:

```
^           # anchor to the start of the string
([^,]+)     # match everything except a comma one or more times
,           # match the comma itself
\s          # match a single whitespace character
([A-Z]{2})  # now match a two letter state code 
(?:         # create a non-capture group
    \s        # match a single whitespace character
    (\d{5})   # match a 5 digit number
)?          # this whole group is optional
$           # anchor to the end of the string
```

Comment: Good answer. The dot-star is _way_ overused! +1

Comment: @ridgerunner - Thanks! Dot-star also makes me nervous because it often is far too greedy and makes the expression brittle.

Answer (score 0):

```
["Beverly Hills, CA 90210", "Beverly Hills, CA"].each do |s|
  m = s.match(/^([^,]*),\s*(\w*)\s*(\d*)?$/)
  $1 # => "Beverly Hills", "Beverly Hills"
  $2 # => "CA", "CA"
  $3 # => "90210", ""
end
```

The # => comments show the results for both runs.

Answer (score 0):

`((?:\w|\s)+),\s(AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)`

Here is a long one which only grabs valid [state codes](http://geography.about.com/od/lists/a/stateabbreviate.htm).